# How do I parse an HTML list with nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to parse a generated HTML file to get the top `<li>` elements.
The structure of the HTML is like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#xyz'>toplevel1</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#nested11'>nested11</a></li>
    <li><a href='#nested12'>nested12</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href='#xxyyzdf'>toplevel2</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#nested21'>nested21</a></li>
    <li><a href='#nested22'>nested22</a></li>
    <li><a href='#nested23'>nested23</a></li>
  </ul>
    ......
</ul>
```

I tried using regex and a little bit Nokogiri, because I am new to Nokogiri.
I didn't find a way to determine which links are the toplevel ones.

The page structure is like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="content" class="view">
    <div id="main-content" class="wiki-content group">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#YXZ-abd1'>toplevel1</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#xyznested11'>nested11</a></li>
            <li><a href='#xyznested12'>nested12</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href='#XZYG-SDF'>toplevel2</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#nxyzested21'>nested21</a></li>
            <li><a href='#xyznested22'>nested22</a></li>
            <li><a href='#xyznested23'>nested23</a></li>
          </ul>
          ......
        </ul>
        ......
```

The structure is so weird, in my opinion, because it's auto-generated HTML coming from confluence.

Comment: I tried stephens solution, which works as long as i copy the links from html into my script. To be honest I donno why the whole html won't work, but i guess its because of the divs before the ul appears. I will take a deeper look into the nokogiri documentation to find out. Thank you all a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it using CSS selectors:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<body>
  <div id="content" class="view">
    <div id="main-content" class="wiki-content group">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href='#YXZ-abd1'>toplevel1</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#xyznested11'>nested11</a></li>
            <li><a href='#xyznested12'>nested12</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href='#XZYG-SDF'>toplevel2</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href='#nxyzested21'>nested21</a></li>
            <li><a href='#xyznested22'>nested22</a></li>
            <li><a href='#xyznested23'>nested23</a></li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
</div></div></div></body>
EOT

top_level = doc.search('div#main-content > div > ul')
puts top_level.to_html
```

Which captured:

```
# >> <ul>
# >> <li><a href="#YXZ-abd1">toplevel1</a></li>
# >>           <ul>
# >> <li><a href="#xyznested11">nested11</a></li>
# >>             <li><a href="#xyznested12">nested12</a></li>
# >>           </ul>
# >> <li><a href="#XZYG-SDF">toplevel2</a></li>
# >>           <ul>
# >> <li><a href="#nxyzested21">nested21</a></li>
# >>             <li><a href="#xyznested22">nested22</a></li>
# >>             <li><a href="#xyznested23">nested23</a></li>
# >>           </ul>
# >> </ul>
```

Getting more specific and finding the next level's `<li>` tags:

```
top_level = doc.search('div#main-content > div > ul > li')
puts top_level.to_html
# >> <li><a href="#YXZ-abd1">toplevel1</a></li><li><a href="#XZYG-SDF">toplevel2</a></li>
```

Grabbing their embedded `<a>` tags:

```
top_level = doc.search('div#main-content > div > ul > li > a')
puts top_level.to_html
# >> <a href="#YXZ-abd1">toplevel1</a><a href="#XZYG-SDF">toplevel2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Nokogiri](http://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri)'s gem. It will let your parse your html using [xpath](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<ul>...</ul>")

# Search for nodes by css
doc.css('a[href*=top]').each do |link|
  # do something here
end
```

Comment: The problem with the html is that it is generated form another source and > 1000 line, so changing the ids to classes would be to much work.

Comment: I see, anyway `nokogiri` will help you parse the html and figure out how. Take a look at examples and doc.

Comment: Ok thx, I will take a deeper look and respond whether i found a good way :)

Comment: @Flo updated my answer take a look at the following css3 selector `'a[href*=top]'`

Comment: Hi Pierre, thx for your answer, but because the auto-generated html i cannot make sure, that there is always a different 'word' in the toplevel links. My example code was badly writen. Sry for that.

Comment: you mean you don't know the ID of the top level elements you want to fetch ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a CSS selector to match only the top level links, the only thing I can think of would be to temporarily wrap the whole string, which you're about to parse with nokogiri, in another easily selectable node.

```
<myselectablenode>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#top1'>toplevel1</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#nested11'>nested11</a></li>
      <li><a href='#nested12'>nested12</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href='#top2'>toplevel2</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#nested21'>nested21</a></li>
      <li><a href='#nested22'>nested22</a></li>
      <li><a href='#nested23'>nested23</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</myselectablenode>
```

Parse your example document fragment with: `doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse("<myselectablenode>" + mydoc + "</myselectablenode>")`
Then access your top level elements with `doc.css("myselectablenode > ul > li")`

Here's a more full example:

```
$ cat > /tmp/scrape
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#top1'>toplevel1</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#nested11'>nested11</a></li>
      <li><a href='#nested12'>nested12</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href='#top2'>toplevel2</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#nested21'>nested21</a></li>
      <li><a href='#nested22'>nested22</a></li>
      <li><a href='#nested23'>nested23</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
^C
~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> contents = File.read("/tmp/scrape")
=> "  <ul>\n    <li><a href='#top1'>toplevel1</a></li>\n    <ul>\n      <li><a href='#nested11'>nested11</a></li>\n      <li><a href='#nested12'>nested12</a></li>\n    </ul>\n    <li><a href='#top2'>toplevel2</a></li>\n    <ul>\n      <li><a href='#nested21'>nested21</a></li>\n      <li><a href='#nested22'>nested22</a></li>\n      <li><a href='#nested23'>nested23</a></li>\n    </ul>\n  </ul>\n"
irb(main):002:0> contents = "<myselectablenode>" + contents + "</myselectablenode>"
=> "<myselectablenode>  <ul>\n    <li><a href='#top1'>toplevel1</a></li>\n    <ul>\n      <li><a href='#nested11'>nested11</a></li>\n      <li><a href='#nested12'>nested12</a></li>\n    </ul>\n    <li><a href='#top2'>toplevel2</a></li>\n    <ul>\n      <li><a href='#nested21'>nested21</a></li>\n      <li><a href='#nested22'>nested22</a></li>\n      <li><a href='#nested23'>nested23</a></li>\n    </ul>\n  </ul>\n</myselectablenode>"
irb(main):003:0> require "rubygems"; require "nokogiri"
=> true
irb(main):004:0> doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse(contents)
=> #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x14031ec name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1402eb8 name="myselectablenode" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1402c38 "  ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1402be8 name="ul" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x14028f0 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14028a0 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14025a8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x14024cc name="href" value="#top1">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1402080 "toplevel1">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1401e78 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1401e28 name="ul" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1401b30 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1401ae0 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14017e8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x140170c name="href" value="#nested11">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x14012d4 "nested11">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x14010cc "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x140107c name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1400d84 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1400ca8 name="href" value="#nested12">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1400870 "nested12">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1400668 "\n    ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1400500 "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14004b0 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14001b8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x14000dc name="href" value="#top2">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13ffca4 "toplevel2">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13ffa9c "\n    ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x13ffa4c name="ul" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13ff754 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x13ff704 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x13ff40c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x13ff330 name="href" value="#nested21">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13feef8 "nested21">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13fecf0 "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x13feca0 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x13fe9a8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x13fe8cc name="href" value="#nested22">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13fe494 "nested22">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13fe28c "\n      ">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x13fe23c name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x13fdf44 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x13fde68 name="href" value="#nested23">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13fda30 "nested23">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13fd828 "\n    ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13fd6c0 "\n  ">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13fd558 "\n">]>]>
irb(main):005:0> doc.css("myselectablenode > ul > li")
=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14028a0 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14025a8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x14024cc name="href" value="#top1">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1402080 "toplevel1">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14004b0 name="li" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x14001b8 name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x14000dc name="href" value="#top2">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x13ffca4 "toplevel2">]>]>]
```

Comment: Awesome! Just inserted your some of the html lines plain into your Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse call and it worked like a charm. So it must also work with the whole file. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: i donno why but it doesn't work with the html file, only when i copy&paste the links. Could this be because of other ul li elements before or not closed divs or something like that?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're describing, so I wrote up a full example of me reading a file and parsing out the top level items with Nokogiri.

Comment: I tried your example. It works, but I prefer the tin Man's answer because in my opinion it is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Nokogiri supports XPath queries. Here is an example XPath query to get a collection of `<a>` nodes whose href contains the phrase 'top':

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(example_html)
top_links = doc.xpath("//li/a[contains(@href, 'top')]")

top_links.size # => 2
top_links.map { |link| link.text } # => ["toplevel1", "toplevel2"]
top_links.map { |link| link.attr('href') } # => ["#top1", "#top2"]
```

XPath queries offer a considerable amount of flexibility, too. In the example below, we want to grab any line item with a class of 'special', but only if it contains a "top link":

```
html = <<-HTML
<ul>
  <li><a href='#top1'>toplevel1</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#nested11'>nested11</a></li>
    <li><a href='#nested12'>nested12</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href='#top2'>toplevel2</a></li>
  <ul>
    <li class='special'><a href='#nested21'>nested21</a></li>
    <li><a href='#nested22'>nested22</a></li>
    <li><a href='#nested23'>nested23</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li class='special'><a href='#top3'>toplevel3</a></li>
</ul>
HTML

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
special_items_with_top_links = doc.xpath('//li[@class="special"]/a[contains(@href, "top")]/..')

puts special_items_with_top_links.size # => 1

special_items_with_top_links.each do |item|
  puts item.to_html 
  # => <li class="special"><a href="#top3">toplevel3</a></li>

  puts "#{item.attr('class')}: #{item.at('a').text}"
  # => special: toplevel3
end
```